# What ways can hasOverlappingRendering result in faulty rendering?

Tags: android, android-view, alphablending, android-viewgroup

From [Google's video on transparency performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&v=wIy8g8yNhNk), it points out that if you override hasOverlappingRendering() to return false, it tells the renderer to avoid hardware layers which saves on drawing costs. However it says if we misuse it and have it return false on content that does have overlapping content, it just won't have 100% correct alpha blending.

What does incorrect alpha blending mean? Just the problem that was pointed out in the beginning, where if alpha is set on a view, any subviews will blend into that view as well rather than blending directly into the root view?

Also are there any other potential negatives to misusing this property? Documentation and discussion is rather sparse on this property altogether.

Comment: I think incorrect alpha blending is what he points out from 1:32 to 2:02 in that video (https://youtu.be/wIy8g8yNhNk?t=1m32s). It's not necessarily a obvious problem.

Comment: As well some more details here --> https://youtu.be/vQZFaec9NpA?t=29m51s